# Adding Kotlin plugins using plugins DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

It looks like there are two ways of declaring *some* Kotlin plugins using plugins DSL: Using the `id()` method and the `kotlin()` method. For example, the android plugin can be added using either `id("kotlin-android")` or [`kotlin("android")`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin#add). This is also the case for [`kapt`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html) but not for [`parcelize`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize). Why can't this be `kotlin("parcelize")`? Is there a reason for this discrepancy? I tried to look up relevant documentation but that didn't get me very far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: Take the Gradle plugin ID for Parcelize and use everything after `org.jetbrains.kotlin.`

```kotlin
plugins {
  kotlin("plugin.parcelize") version "1.6.10"
}
```

---

The `kotlin(...)` function is part of the Gradle Kotlin DSL. It is an extension function that extends

1. PluginDependenciesSpec, the `plugins {}` block
2. DependencyHandler, the `dependencies {}` block

I'm going to focus on the Plugin extension function. Some of this answer is applicable to the Dependency extension.

### `kotlin(...)` source code

It's generated so it's difficult to see the source code. I dug through GitHub and found it in [GenerateKotlinDependencyExtensions.kt](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v7.4.0/build-logic/kotlin-dsl/src/main/kotlin/gradlebuild/kotlindsl/generator/tasks/GenerateKotlinDependencyExtensions.kt#L105)

```kotlin
fun PluginDependenciesSpec.kotlin(module: String): PluginDependencySpec =
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.$module")
```

(edited, to show the end result)

### `kotlin(...)` = `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.$module")`

So it's nothing special. It's a Kotlin-specific shortcut for `id(...)`. So if you

1. take the plugin ID for [Parcelize](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize), `org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize`,
2. and remove the bits that the `kotlin(...)` function adds (`org.jetbrains.kotlin.`),
3. you're left with `plugin.parcelize`.

> **NOTE** Because this is in the `plugins {}` block, it's working on the Gradle plugin ID (`org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize`), *not* the Maven coordinates (`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin`).

```kotlin
plugins {
  // these two are equivalent
  // id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize")
  kotlin("plugin.parcelize")
}
```

Oh wait... it doesn't work??

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/.../build.gradle.kts' line: 3
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

### "Build failed with an exception" - Plugin version

That's because unlike the `DependencyHandler.kotlin(...)` extension, the `PluginDependenciesSpec.kotlin(...)` **doesn't include the version**. It says that in the error message: "plugin dependency must include a version number"

So to resolve it, add a version number.

```kotlin
plugins {
  kotlin("plugin.parcelize") version "1.6.10"
}
```

### Other Kotlin plugins

The same goes for [the other Kotlin plugins](https://plugins.gradle.org/u/kotlin). For example...

```kotlin
plugins {

  // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html
  kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.6.10"

  // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#spring-support
  kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.10"

  // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html
  kotlin("plugin.noarg") version "1.6.10"

  // I can't find a Gradle Plugin ID for 
  // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sam-with-receiver-plugin.html
  // so this won't work!
  // kotlin("kotlin-sam-with-receiver") version "1.6.10"
}
```

Comment: My goodness, what a beautiful answer. Thank you.

Comment: Nice answer, but why the version is needed on that format and otherwise it isn't? It seems as a drawback in that sense.

Comment: @htafoya Chicken and egg... `dependencies { kotlin() }` is provided by the Kotlin Gradle plugin, and so the version can default to be the same as Kotlin plugin version. However, `plugins { kotlin() }` is part of Gradle, and so Gradle needs to be told what Kotlin plugin version to download. You can avoid specifying a version in `plugins {}` in a few ways, for example by [using buildSrc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71883613/4161471).