# Custom Configuration dependency declaration

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to convert build.gradle to kotlin dsl. Using gradle 7.4.1.What the right way to declare custom configuration. For custom configuration like

```
    configurations { grafana }
    
    sourceSets { grafana }
```

and within dependencies block

```
    grafanaImplementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36"
    grafanaImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    grafanaRuntimeOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
```

While I am in kotlin-dsl I am doing

```
    val grafana by configurations.creating
    
    val grafanaSourceSet = sourceSets.create("grafana")
```

and within dependency block

```
  grafana("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36")
  grafana("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
```

When I try to put grafanaImplementation/ grafanaRuntimeOnly within kotlin dsl, it fails.

What is the equivalent of  grafanaImplementation/ grafanaRuntimeOnly within kotlin dsl

Answer (score 2):

#### Quick fix

When you do

```kotlin
val grafanaSourceSet = sourceSets.create("grafana")
```

behind the scenes Gradle will create the required configurations, `grafanaImplementation`, `grafanaRuntimeOnly`, etc, so you can use them without error like this:

```kotlin
val grafanaSourceSet = sourceSets.create("grafana")

dependencies {
  "grafanaImplementation"("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
  "grafanaRuntimeOnly"("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36")
}
```

This approach is more like how Groovy works - it basically disables type-checking and the strings will be evaluated during Gradle execution.

#### Generated DSL accessors

However, string-typing is not why we like Kotlin! We want type-safety and auto completion hints. That's exactly what we see with the `implementation()` and `runtimeOnly()`. So how do we get them for `grafanaImplementation()` and `grafanaRuntimeOnly()`?

Basically, Gradle will scan the registered config and when it sees that a plugin creates an `implementation` configuration, it generates [Kotlin DSL accessors](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors). However, it can't generate accessors for the `build.gradle.kts` that contains the definition for the accessors... that's too late. So we need to define the config earlier. We can do that with a buildSrc plugin.

##### buildSrc Grafana convention plugin

1. Set up a buildSrc project (this is covered more in the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html) or  [other StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71892685/4161471))
2. Create a pre-compiled script plugin for Grafana config

   ```kotlin
   // $projectRoot/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/grafana.convention.gradle.kts

   plugins {
     // using 'sourceSets' requires the Java plugin, so we must apply it
     java
   }

   val grafanaSourceSet = sourceSets.create("grafana")
   ```

   Note that this convention plugin is quite opinionated as it applies the Java plugin. In more complex setups you might want to instead [react to the Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#reacting_to_plugins), rather than always applying it.
3. Now apply the convention plugin, and Gradle will generate the Kotlin DSL accessors!

   ```kotlin
   // $projectRoot/build.gradle.kts

   plugins {
     id("grafana.convention")
   }

   dependencies {
     // no string-typing needed!
     grafanaImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
     grafanaRuntimeOnly("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36")
   }
   ```