# Multi-module Gradle project - selectively managing dependencies in child modules

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, multi-module, hexagonal-architecture

Lets say I have a multi-module Gradle Kotlin project. The structure is as follows:

- `main` - app runner + gluing everything together
- `modules`

  - `users`

    - `users-adapters`
    - `users-domain`
  - `orders`

    - `orders-adapters`
    - `orders-domain`

Now - I wanted to be able to manage dependencies selectively. My intentions are:

1. 3rd party libraries like Web library, SQL library, etc. are declared in their versions once, centrally (all modules use same versions of given library).
2. All `domain` modules are **completely 3rd party agnostic**. No 3rd party library should be available on classpath here.
3. All `adapters` modules should be able to receive all or choose selectively the 3rd party dependencies declared somewhere centrally.

I was thinking about `subprojects {}` declaration in root `build.gradle.kts` but this would impact **all** modules, while I want to leave `domain` ones untouched.

Is there a way so that I can have like:

- one "global" dependencies list
- one "for adapters" dependencies list
- one "for domains" dependencies list

How to achieve this?

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid using `allprojects {}` and `subprojects {}`, they're [not recommended by Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins_vs_cross_configuration). Instead you can use buildSrc convention plugins, which are a much more practical solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71892685/4161471

Comment: However buildSrc plugins are not great for version alignment of dependencies. Instead I prefer the [Java Version Platform plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html). Create a separate subproject, define _all_ versions that are necessary, and the other subprojects can 'import' the version platform subproject.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experimenting with the hexagonal architecture with Gradle myself and
I have found the following setup working quite well for me.

(Please excuse for using the `Kotlin DSL` as I only have one repo to demo while
time of writing this answer).

To start off, here is the package structure I follow:

```
<project root>
|     build.gradle.kts
|     ...
└───  apps
|     └───  <putting everything together>
|           |     build.gradle.kts
|           |     ...
└───  core
|     └───  <business logic>
|           |     build.gradle.kts
|           |     ...
└───  libs
      └───  <some common lib>
            |     build.gradle.kts
            |     ...
```

---

Let's focus on `build.gradle.kts` in project root:

```
plugins {
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.12.RELEASE"
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")

    dependencyManagement {
        dependencies {
            dependency("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11")           
            dependency("org.javamoney:moneta:1.4.2")
            dependency("nl.hiddewieringa:money-kotlin:1.0.1")
            dependencySet("io.jsonwebtoken:0.11.5") {
                entry("jjwt-api")
                entry("jjwt-impl")
            }
        }
    }
}

configure(subprojects) {
    dependencies {
        implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
        testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    }

    tasks.test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

Quick explanation,
I am using [Spring IO's Gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.spring.dependency-management) which enables
declaration of packages and their version across projects in one place.
If you observe, I only apply this plugin across subprojects.
Now in the configuration, I keep common configs applicable to all the subprojects.

---

Let's jump to `core -> build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
    api("nl.hiddewieringa:money-kotlin")
}
```

Here you can see the core only uses `money-kotlin` (Kotlin extensions for javax.money)
which is api only.
Note that since logger is defined in the configuration for the subproject, I can use that in core logic to define logs.
Also, versions are acquired from the ones mentioned in the main Gradle file.

Something similar would go for `libs -> build.gradle.kts`.

---

Finally `apps -> build.gradle.kts` looks like:

```
dependencies {
    api("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api")
    api("nl.hiddewieringa:money-kotlin")
    implementation("org.javamoney:moneta")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl")
}
```

Here, I am applying the actual implementation of java-money using `moneta` (separating logic and api from actual impl).
Similarly, `jjwt` is only applied here.

This way, all the versions are controlled in a single place. Logic gets separated out of impl details.
As I see, this covers most things needed for hexagonal pattern.
Hope it helps.