# How to add gradle dependency when buildFeature.compose = true?

Tags: gradle, android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Each time when a module needs enabled compose I have to do the following steps:

1. android.buildFeatures.compose = true
2. add a set of dependencies androidx.compose.xxx

I have a common build script and now I want to simplify usage of compose in my modules.

I would like to simplify that process by automatically add all compose dependencies if child module enables compose by android.buildFeatures.compose = true

How can I do it?

Comment: Using [precompiled script plugins in `buildSrc`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins) is the best way to define repetitive Gradle config. There's a similar example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71892685/4161471

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is done in the [Now in android](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) example app. They are using gradle plugins to do that, you can see common logic for all jetpack compose modules here: [AndroidCompose.kt](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/e7b2ed623e24cdb4711ed4a7b45d6615d42ad2f4/build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/AndroidCompose.kt). There is a [readme](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/4683918cc7da6593edea6dca1ea662eea76d3b7b/build-logic/README.md) that explains it pretty well.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I have implemented the same solution )