# How to create reusable task in gradle multi-module project?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multi-module gradle project and it seems that I need some common task, or a root task, that can be run on each child project with different parameters. My project structure is:

```
-+ parent
 |  /gradle
 |  build.gradle.kts
 |  settings.gradle.kts
 |  gradlew
 |  gradlew.bat
 +- child1
 |    /build
 |    build.gradle.kts
 +- child2
 |    /build
 |    build.gradle.kts
 +- child3
 |    /build
 |    build.gradle.kts
 +- child4
 |    /build
 |    build.gradle.kts
```

I need to run jacoco test coverage tasks only at `child2`, `child3`, and `child4` projects **with individual minimum value**.

So I can't define a task in the `subprojects` section of root `build.gradle.kts`, because it will be applied to all subprojects.

Also as an alternative, it seems that I can define a task in the root `build.gradle.kts` and call it `dependsOn(":parent:myTask")` but in this case I can't use parameterization...

I'm not very familiar with this, so could anyone explain the right way it should be done, or maybe point to a good example of similar functionality?

Comment: The trick is to create a convention plugin. There's [an example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html) in the Gradle docs, and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883613/configure-kotlin-extension-for-gradle-subprojects/71892685#71892685) on a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's many ways to go about this, but how about something like this...  The task can live in the root `build.gradle`, and you can parse the project name and define your value specifically (you could also skip sub-projects you don't want to do it in).  For example...

```
tasks.register("jill") {
    doLast {
        println("Jill was here")
    }
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        var value = 0
        if (project.name == "child1") value = 45
        if (project.name == "child2") value = 73
        if (project.name == "child3") value = 61
        if (project.name == "child4") value = 38
        tasks.register("jones") {
            doLast {
                println("PROJECT [$value]: ${project.name}")
            }
        }
        tasks.findByPath(":jill").finalizedBy(project.tasks.findByName("jones"))
    }
}
```

Explaining the solution a moment...  Looping through all projects, set `value` based on project name.  Then, register a task in each sub-project which will do some stuff (mine prints project name and computed value).

Then, since you mentioned it, it connects all of these new tasks (`jones`) to a task in the root project (`jill`).

Finally, you can simply run `./gradlew jill`.  It runs the main tasks, and finalizes it by all of the created tasks in the child projects, each with self-awareness of their own values.

```
> Task :jill
Jill was here

> Task :child4:jones
PROJECT [38]: child4

> Task :child3:jones
PROJECT [61]: child3

> Task :child2:jones
PROJECT [73]: child2


> Task :child1:jones
PROJECT [45]: child1
```