# Use Kotlin plugins from buildSrc

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-gradle-plugin, buildsrc

How can I apply the Kotlin plugins from a buildSrc plugin?

I have a Kotlin project with a build.gradle.kts file containing this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
}
```

I want to create a custom plugin in buildSrc:

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper

class MyPlugin: Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.pluginManager.apply("org.gradle.application") //This works
        project.pluginManager.apply("¿kotlin(jvm)?") //<-- Here is my doubt
        project.pluginManager.apply("¿kotlin(plugin.serialization)?") //<-- Here is my doubt
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.example.myplugin")
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply Gradle plugins from within buildSrc plugins you need to do two things

1. Add the plugins as dependencies in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

   Plugins must be added as dependencies using the *Maven coordinates*, not the plugin ID†. The Maven coordinates of plugins can be found in the Gradle plugin portal.

   - https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm
   - https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization

   ```kotlin
   // buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

   plugins {
     `kotlin-dsl`
   }

   dependencies {
     // the Maven coordinates of the Kotlin Gradle and Serialization plugins
     implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20")
     implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.7.20")
   }
   ```
2. apply the plugins, either using the class, or the plugin ID.

   (Note that `kotlin("jvm")` is [a helper function that obscures the actual Gradle plugin ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71152946/4161471), which is `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm`)

   ```kotlin
   class MyPlugin: Plugin<Project> {
     override fun apply(project: Project) {

       project.pluginManager.apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
       project.pluginManager.apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization")

       // the plugin class for the Kotlin JVM & Serialization plugins
       project.plugins.apply(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper::class)
       project.plugins.apply(org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.gradle.SerializationGradleSubplugin::class)
     }
   }
   ```

   (it wasn't easy to find the plugin classes - I had to dig around in the jar to find the [plugin marker artifact](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers), e.g. `kotlin-serialization-1.7.20-gradle71.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization.properties`)

#### Precompiled script plugins

You might also like to use [precompiled script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins). They allow for writing buildSrc script plugins that much more similar to standard `build.gradle.kts` files, and so you can apply plugins in the plugins block.

```kotlin
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/conventions/kotlin-jvm.gradle.kts

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm")
}
```

To enable precompiled script plugins, make sure you've applied the [`kotlin-dsl` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin) in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`.

```kotlin
// buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

#### Error: Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version

What happens when you apply the above steps and you get an error `Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version`?

There are a lot of ways to specify the version of a Gradle plugin (far too many in my opinion!). If you're updating an existing project with the above steps, you've just used one more way of specifying a version, and Gradle is spitting out an unhelpful error message.

The way to fix it is to limit the number of ways your project specifies Gradle plugin versions. What's probably happened is that you've added a plugin in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` that you *also* apply in the plugins block of a subproject. Gradle will get confused about which version of the plugin you want.

The way to fix it is to only specify the plugin version in a single place, and that place is as a dependency in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`.

```kotlin
// my-cool-subproject/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm")// version "1.9.0" // version is not necessary, it's specified in buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
}
```

---

###### Footnotes

† Note that it is actually possible to use the plugin ID as a regular dependency, with some manipulation. Gradle can discover plugins from *any* Maven repository via the [Plugin Marker Artifact](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers). Given a plugin ID the Maven GAV coordinates can be determined as follows:

```kotlin
val kmpPluginId = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform"
val kmpPluginVersion = "1.9.0"
val kmpMavenGav = "${kmpPluginId}:${kmpPluginId}.gradle.plugin:${kmpPluginVersion}"
```