# How to declare plugins using `libs.versions.toml` with `kotlin` functions?

Tags: gradle

The normal way is this:

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"
```

when I use `libs.versions.toml`:

```
[plugins]
kotlin-jvm = { module = "jvm", version.ref = "kotlin" }
```

How should plugins be declared in `build.gradle.kts`?

I already know a way to achieve the requirement, but I still want to know how to do it using `kotlin` functions:

```
// libs.versions.toml
kotlin-jvm = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "kotlin" }

// build.gradle.kts
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.jvm)
```

How I get the id of the plugin through `libs...`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Kotlin plugins using plugins DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71152946/adding-kotlin-plugins-using-plugins-dsl)

Comment: @aSemy No, this question is asking about the principle of `kotlin()`, what I am looking for is the usage of `kotlin()`.

Comment: I apologise, I misunderstood what you were asking for. You should be able to get the plugin ID with `libs.plugins.nexusPublish.get().pluginId`. However, I don't know if it will work with the `kotlin()` plugin ID shortcut.

Comment: @aSemy you're right. I use `kotlin(libs.plugins.kotlin.jpa.get().pluginId)` compile successfully, haven't run yet but I believe it should work.

Comment: Sorry for not answering the question, but I'd like to say that the `alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.jvm)` approach is perfectly fine. Moreover, the build script can even be easier to read (at least for me) when `alias` is used consistently to declare all kinds of dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way I have found to do this.

```
plugins {
kotlin(libs.plugins.serialization.get().pluginId).version(libs.versions.kotlin).apply(false)
}
```

```
[versions]
kotlin="1.9.10"
[plugins]
serialization = { id = "plugin.serialization", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
```

ref: https://github.com/avwie/kotlinx/blob/main/build.gradle.kts

Comment: Or this I think is even cleaner. The important part to me is having the centralized version. `kotlin("plugin.serialization").version(libs.versions.kotlin).apply(false)`